# Creating an array of Objects which will contain 4 variables

Tags: javascript, react-native

Im trying to create an array of objects that will hold 4 variables, i managed to create an array of objects that holds 2 variables but i'm stuck right now.

I have this array:

```
Checking =>  Array [
  Object {
    "count": 3,
    "serviceType": "manicure",
  },
  Object {
    "count": 2,
    "serviceType": "Learn JavaScript",
  },
  Object {
    "count": 1,
    "serviceType": "Learn React",
  },
]
```

Coming out from this code(first part):

```
const arrayofServices  = services; //services => state the holding the services
        const servicesCounter = arrayofServices.reduce((counterObj, service) => {
          if (counterObj.hasOwnProperty(service)) {
            counterObj[service] += 1;
            return counterObj;
        }
        
          return {
            ...counterObj,
            [service]: 1
          };
        }, {});
        console.log("Service Counter in UseEffect" ,servicesCounter);
        setServiceObj(servicesCounter);
```

and this code:

```
const res = {};
     const arrayOfValues = Object.values(serviceObj); //Counter values
     const arrayOfKeys = Object.keys(serviceObj); //serviceType values
     arrayOfKeys.forEach((key, i) => (res[key] = arrayOfValues[i]));
     const dat = {... res};

     const array = [];
     for(const [key,value] of Object.entries(dat)){
       array.push({serviceType: key, count: value});
     }
     console.log("Checking => ", array); //Descending Order.
```

What i want to do is to add to "array" another parameters so the form will look like this:

```
  Object {
    "count": 1,
    "serviceType": "Learn React",
    "voucherCode": "f34dty",
    "expDate:" //pass here end of the month date
  },
```

I have created an array of voucerCodes and a variable of the lastDay of moth

suggestions?

Comment: will like to see content of `arrayofServices`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var date = new Date();
var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);
const voucherCode = ['dLHFVd',"6VqLgA","FgTRUp"];
var i = 0;
for(const [key,value] of Object.entries(dat)){
    array.push({
     serviceType: key, 
     count: value,
     voucherCode: voucherCode[i],
     expDate: lastDay.getDate(),
    });
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Its working, but i will need to pass to voucher code from here: const voucherCode = ['dLHFVd',"6VqLgA","FgTRUp"];